# Import popup not displaying

Tags: class, intellij-idea, import

In my IntelliJ, auto import pop-up is not displaying although "show import pop-up" is ticked in the settings so I always have to manually type import java.util..... at the top.

I found some similar questions and tried out their solutions, but none of them worked.

I'm new to Java and started using IntelliJ just a week ago, but if I remember correctly the pop-up was displayed at first. 
I didn't update any settings and have no clue how I can make it back.

Also, unlike many screenshots of other people's intelliJ, the color of code in my intelliJ are all white except for some keywords which are orange and string which is green.

Not sure if it has something to do with this issue tho.

Could anyone help me find out what could be a problem?

Comment: Maybe you can try to reinstall the IntelliJ.

Comment: Are the issues reproduced for you with IDEA 2019.3? (https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/) Can you please share the screenshots of the issues. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below instruction, by that you can fix your issues.

1) Go to setting and in the Settings/Preferences dialog (Ctrl+Alt+S), click Editor | General | Auto Import.

2) Select the Add unambiguous imports on the fly checkbox, and apply the changes.

3) After apply the changes , restart the Intellij idea.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out "Power Save Mode" was on, which caused this problem.
I turned it on now and the issue was solved.